# I want to dynamically create button to pass id

Tags: android

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        Button btn = new Button(this); 
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 45));
        btn.setId(i);
        linearLayout.addView(btn); 
        try {
           btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent userTry = new Intent(Ed.this,Op.class);
                    startActivity(userTry);
                }
            });
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Log.e("onCreate", "Activity Not Found", anfe);
        }
```

Android : I want to dynamically create button such that it passes it id to the next activity it goes to. But i am getting an error. Thanks for the help

Comment: "an error" is not useful information. Please add more details: what error exactly? On what line? What have you tried to fix it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to pass the Bundle with the id:

```
Intent userTry = new Intent(Ed.this,Op.class);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt("EXTRA_PARAM1", yourParam);
userTry.putExtras(extras);

startActivity(userTry);
```

Also, you are setting the id in a wrong way. The method setId (int) is expecting an id which is registered in your resources (e.g, R.id.itemId)